# SQL query if more than 1 row exsists return 0

Tags: sql, sql-server

Maybe someone can help me with the following problem. I have a query which returns records.

But when it has 1 or more rows, I want to receive 0 rows. I think the query should look like:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Names nm WHERE nm.Username = '%a%')
BEGIN
    -- I should return 0 rows if the query above has rows
END
```

Comment: yes that works,are you facing any issue

Comment: i dont know which script i should place between BEGIN and END.

Comment: What do you want when it has 0 rows?  The logic doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: are you looking to exit when it has zero rows

Comment: what would you want to get back if the where clause doesn't return any results?

Comment: Wouldn't that mean you always receive zero rows back?

Comment: Title says "more than 1" but text says "1 or more".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below code might help:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Names nm WHERE nm.Username = '%a%')
BEGIN
        -- It should return 0 rows if the query above has rows
        SELECT * FROM Names nm WHERE 1=2;

END
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want one row (if it exists) or no rows, you could do:

```
SELECT *
FROM Names nm
WHERE nm.Username = '%a%' AND
      (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Names nm WHERE nm.Username = '%a%') <= 1;
```

However, this won't distinguish between no matches and more than one match.

Comment: There's no way around it - you have to query the tables twice.  Once for the potential result set and the other to determine the (awkward) logic in the `where` clause.  +1

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return an empty resultset with just the columns structure you can use

```
SELECT * 
FROM Names 
WHERE 1=0
```

or

```
SELECT TOP 0 * 
FROM Names
```

both queries returns an empty resultset with the columns structure of the Names table.

Answer (score 0):

You can write like below.

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Names nm WHERE nm.Username = '%a%')
BEGIN
     SELECT * FROM Names WHERE 1=0
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Along with Gordon's answer perhaps these are helpful. It appears you're only interested in returning a result when there's only a single username that matches some pattern.

```
-- just the username
select min(nm.Username) as Username
from Names nm
where nm.Username = '%a%'
having count(*) = 1

-- all the columns
select * from
    (
    select *, count(*) over () as cnt
    from Names nm
    where nm.Username = '%a%'
    )
where cnt = 1
```

You'll have to list out the individual column names if you don't want to see `cnt` in the output.